# Angular Js Bind Text box with JSON Array with Static Index

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have 5 fixed Textbox, I have a JSON Array which should be bind with Textbox. 0th index element will be bind with 1st textbox.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control col-md-5" ng-model="jsonArray[0].amount">
```

what should i need to put in **ng-model**?

in jsonArray have 5 Json Object but nothing will displayed in Textbox.

Comment: Plese give sample json format and what you have written in controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In controller you assign to a variable and bind it,

**Controller**

```
$scope.amount = jsonArray[0].amount;
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control col-md-5" ng-model="amount">
```